# Cron job is not running

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I've tried just about everything to get my cron script to work but am not having any luck. I've been through many mini tutorial several times too! Here's what I'm trying to run...

```
    /usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/yourfilename.php
```

On cpanel even i am not getting email after running time of my crone job.
thank you

Comment: Is the path to your file correct? Did you replace "username" to your name on the server?

Comment: yes everything is correct and is there any way to run this script manually with my server to check the script.But errors also should come to given mail id.

Comment: Well, can't you run the script through the browser... ?

Comment: yes it is working on browser..

Comment: Do i need to contact my host provider admin?

Comment: Show your line in `crontab`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/yourfilename.php >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check below points.

1. The file location is correct.
2. check that the crond services running or not. you can check with below commend :

   ## /etc/init.d/crond status

and you should get status running with pid. if you can got it then move on point 3 otherwise. try to restart the cron service via below command:

## /etc/init.d/crond restart

and check the logs via below command :

## tail -f /var/log/cron

3. if you getting the cron service working then check your lfd service working on not.

   ## /etc/init.d/lfd status

if its running then check your email proper configure on lfd.

4. if lfd fine then run below command as root to add cron

   ## crontab -e

give your cron at the end of file with correct format.

sure that time it will work.

if getting any issue in any point. let me know here.

Comment: All of the above is very useful, but I believe you cannon run any shell commands from cpanel...

Comment: yes right, you cann't run the commands from cpanel. upper commands will work from shell. but you can login on shell via root user and you can fix the issue with in few seconds.